# How to get a dict with index and value of certain column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this toy dataset:

```
cat         count   class_weight
cars        17824    0.000404
bus         124784   0.000553
planes      111271   0.000620
```

I want to output a `dictionary` with **index** and **class_weight** values, like this:

```
 {0: 0.000404,
    1: 0.000553,
    2: 0.000620}
```

**I am doing:**

```
class_weight = {}
for index, label in enumerate(categories):
    class_weight[index] = df[df['cat'] == categories]['class_weight'].values[0]
```

`categories` is a `numpy.ndarray` with the `cat` values

and my output is wrong because the `values[0` is returning the first value for all car items:

```
   {0: 0.000404,
    1: 0.000404,
    2: 0.000404}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html)'s default output is what you're looking for.

Given:

```
      cat   count  class_weight
0    cars   17824      0.000404
1     bus  124784      0.000553
2  planes  111271      0.000620
```

Doing:

```
x = df.class_weight.to_dict()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
{
 0: 0.000404, 
 1: 0.000553, 
 2: 0.00062
}
```